# VBA: About go back to target(sheet change event) cell or at least that target sheet after below procedures

Tags: excel, vba

I am a beginner of VBA :D I am creating LogSheet to record any changes from sheets. From beginning I want to check if the 'LogSheet' exists already when sheetchange event fired. So I put this 'check procedures' at beginning of SheetChange event. But the annoying thing is if 'Logsheet' not existing then It creats one and the active sheet switch to that new created 'LogSheet'.

My question is if there could be a method: after change event fired and new LogSheet created, the selection will go back to the target that I just changed before, rather than stay in 'LogSheet'.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB971.png)

Comment: copy your code from VBA IDE and paste it in the question enclosed in code tags

Comment: Move your code to post so it can be copied. You may add a line `Application.EnableEvents = false` before the line `sheets.add` and `Application.EnableEvents = true` after the line with MsgBox which reports about sheet's creation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edited to add more about `Me` keyword

to activate your "calling" sheet just use

```
Me.Activate
```

since in any code in a sheet code pane the keyword `Me` refers to the sheet itself

but you could also benefit from a "helper" function (explanation in comments):

```
Function CreateSheet(shtName As String, sht As Worksheet) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next'prevent possible next statement error to stop code execution
    Set sht = Worksheets(shtName)' try setting the sheet with passed name
    On Error GoTo 0' restore default error handling
    If sht Is Nothing Then' if there was not such sheet with passed name
        Set sht = Worksheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))' set a new one
    sht.Name = shtName' give new sheet the passed name  
        Me.Activate' activate back the "calling" sheet
        CreateSheet = True'return 'True' and have calling sub know that a new sheet hase been created and passed back via 'sht' parameter
    End If
End Function
```

this function must reside 
not to clutter your `Change` event sub, as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim logSht As Worksheet

    If CreateSheet("Logsheet", logSht) Then
        logSht.Range("A1:O1").Value = Array(...)
        MsgBox "Log Sheet has been created ..."
    Else
        MsgBox "Log Sheet has already been created BEFORE..."
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your code simplifies mine. But there's a error. Please refer to picture I submit.

Comment: Sorry mate, I just updated the error pic above, maybe I need to submit JPG. But  please refer to the link called "Error from me.activate"

Comment: that has nothing to do with your _original_ question, which I answered with a working solution (i tested myself) for the environment given. If you have another issue, you should make a new post after giving proper feedback to answers to the _original_ question

Comment: a for the update error pic, se my update answer: the `CreateSheet()` function must reside in the sheet  code pane (the same where the `Change()` event is) in order to use `Me` keyword

Comment: CreateSheet() relocates to Change() event sheet now and no error appears now. But after change event fired, select switch to LogSheet anyway. Is that because logSht.range().Value = Array?

Comment: `logSht.range().Value = Array` in itself wouldn't switch sheet along